# derivative transpose

Tags: matrices, derivatives, linear-regression, transpose

I'm reading the book "The Elements of Statistical Learning - Data Mining, Inference, and Prediction" chapter 3 and there comes a simple derivation that I don't understand:

We have:                   $$(1): RSS(\beta) = (y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta)$$

with input X is N × (p + 1) matrix, (p+1) column is 1, $X_1$,$X_2$, ... $X_p$; y is N-vector output.

The question is when differentiating with  respect to $\beta$ why we obtain this ?
$$(2):  \frac{\partial RSS}{\partial \beta} = -2X^T(y-X\beta)  $$ 
An answer that explain how to differentiate RSS with respect to $\beta$ will be highly appreciated

Comment: What should the last equation mean ?

Comment: Well if (3) is true then we have an explanation for (2), which is my question

Comment: Quote: "Anyway an answer that explain how to differentiate RSS with respect to β will be highly appreciated" I hope this is true.

Comment: My question was, what the meaning of (3) is, especially the LHS. Show more effort or delete your question.

Comment: Now after reading ur answer I realize this is just my misunderstanding. Alrdy delete it. Thanks

Comment: Think of a prefix transpose as the dot product $x^\top x = x \cdot x$ and the postfix transpose as the outer product $x\,x^\top = x \odot x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can multiply out the brackets:

$RSS(\beta) = (y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta)=(y^T-\beta^TX^T)(y-X\beta)$

$=y^Ty-y^TX\beta-\beta^TX^Ty+\beta^TX^TX\beta$

The second and the third summands are scalars. Therefore $y^TX\beta=\beta^TX^Ty$.

$=y^Ty-2\beta^TX^Ty+\beta^TX^TX\beta$

Now we can differentiate RSS w.r.t $\beta$. The first summand become $0$. The second summand becomes $-2X^Ty$ and the third summand becomes $2X^TX\beta$. The rules of differentiation can be directly derived.
Thus we get

$\frac{\partial RSS}{\partial \beta}=-2X^Ty+2X^TX\beta=0$

---

Update:

You can substitute $X^Ty$ by $Z$. I ommit the factor 2. Then we have

$$\frac{\partial\beta^T \cdot Z }{\partial \beta}$$

We can use the property $$\frac{\partial \beta^TZ}{\partial \beta}=\left(\frac{\partial (\beta^TZ)^T}{\partial \beta^T}\right)^T=\left(\frac{\partial Z^T\beta}{\partial \beta^T}\right)^T \qquad (*)$$

An example shows that this is true.

$Z=\left(\begin{array}{} z_{11}& z_{12}\\z_{21}&z_{22} \end{array}\right),\beta
=\left(\begin{array}{} \beta_1 \\\beta_2 \end{array}\right)$

$Z^T\cdot \beta=\left(\begin{array}{} z_{11}& z_{21}\\z_{12}&z_{22} \end{array}\right)\cdot \left(\begin{array}{} \beta_1 \\\beta_2 \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{} z_{11}\beta_1& z_{21}\beta_2\\z_{12}\beta_1&z_{22}\beta_2 \end{array}\right)$

$$\frac{\partial Z^T\cdot \beta}{\partial \beta^T}=\frac{\partial \left(\begin{array}{} z_{11}\beta_1& z_{21}\beta_2\\z_{12}\beta_1&z_{22}\beta_2 \end{array}\right)}{\partial \left(\begin{array}{} \beta_1 &\beta_2 \end{array}\right)}=\left(\begin{array}{} z_{11}& z_{21}\\z_{12}&z_{22}\end{array}\right)=Z^T$$

With $(*)$ we see that $$\frac{\partial\beta^T \cdot Z }{\partial \beta}=Z=X^Ty$$.

Comment: Very clear & quick answer. Thanks !

Comment: @TuanVietNguyen You are welcome.

Comment: How come the beta transposes disappear before the regular betas? What is this process called when you differentiate equations where the variables represent matrices?

Comment: @calcstudent I have made an update.